# Chrome crashes when selenium launches a website

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I am trying to open a website on chrome via selenium with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s=Service('C:/Users/Morteza/Documents/Dev/chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url='https://www.google.com'
browser.get(url)
```

link to problem: https://share.cleanshot.com/p1qu5y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue or crash. After the specified actions are completed successfully, selenium closes the web browser. This program works fine.

Use the following code with a while True block

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't any crash or an error as such. Selenium automatically closes the client i.e. the *Chrome Browser* instance after executing the last line of your code. However this practice may accumulate *undeleted*/*zombie* ***chromedriver*** instances within your system.

Ideally, you always need to invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully at the end of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

the chromedrive path in your code, i guess your platform is `windows`.

but the picture you post revease that your machine is `mac`.

pay attention to `the chromedriver file PATH` and `your PC platform`, make sure they suit to each other.

or you could put chromedriver in `system PATH variable`, so you do not need to specify the chromedrive path in your code